# Memorymanagement when getting a NSMutableArray from NSObject class to UIViewController class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I have problem with the following code leaking memory...

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *childrensArray;


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSLog(@"Connection finished loading.");  
// Dismiss the network indicator when connection finished loading
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

// Parse the responseData of json objects retrieved from the service
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonData = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];
childrensArray = [jsonData objectForKey:@"Children"];

// Callback to AttendanceReportViewController that the responseData finished loading
[attendanceReportViewController loadChildren];

[connection release];
[responseData release];
[jsonString release];
[parser release]; 
}
```

In the viewController the following also leaks memory...

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *childrensArray;


- (void)loadChildren {

// Retrieve a array with dictionaries of children from ServiceGetChildren
self.childrensArray = [[serviceGetChildren.childrensArray copy] autorelease];   

int total = [childrensArray count];
totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", total]; 

[theTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: could you clean up the code of you post, please.

Comment: I'm just saying, but.. after your line of leaks (`childrensArray = [serviceGetChildren.childrensArray copy];` you have a `{` instead of a `}`. Also, I hope that this isn't fully copy pasted all in once, but copy pasted in parts, right? Because if the layout is exactly the same, there are more.. ahum, things, wrong.

Comment: @toto yes of course sorry for that. Now probably more easy to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only release `childrensArray` when the instance is deallocated. You should also release the instance variable before setting it:

```
- (void)loadChildren {
    // Retrieve a array with dictionaries of children from ServiceGetChildren 
    [childrensArray release];
    childrensArray = [serviceGetChildren.childrensArray copy]; 
}
```

A better way would be to actually use your property:

```
- (void)loadChildren {
    // Retrieve a array with dictionaries of children from ServiceGetChildren 
    self.childrensArray = [[serviceGetChildren.childrensArray copy] autorelease]; 
}
```

(Note the `autorelease`)

This has the benefit of triggering KVO-Notifications should you ever use them.

Comment: Another problem is `childrensArray = [jsonData objectForKey:@"Children"];`, which is overwriting the childrensArray instance variable without releasing it. A temporary variable should be used instead.

Comment: Ok, if I do self.childrensArray = [[serviceGetChildren.childrensArray copy] autorelease]; 

I dont need to release it in dealloc?

Comment: @Tony Ok but if I use a temporary variable, how can i then retrieve it from the viewController? Do I still set it´s property? Or how do you mean?

Comment: @Silversnail Okay, I didn't realize these were two different classes. It should be `self.childrensArray = [jsonData objectForKey:@"Children"]`, so that you release whatever childrensArray pointed to before and retain the new value. In your viewController, the updated code you have is fine, i.e., `self.childrensArray = [[serviceGetChildren.childrensArray copy] autorelease]`, except it should be `mutableCopy` instead (you are assigning to an NSMutableArray).